# Trouble importing/replacing a table w CSV in phpMyAdmin: Invalid column count in CSV input on line 1

Tags: php, sql, csv, phpmyadmin

I am trying to swap out a table in phpMyAdmin with new data.
I have scoured the web trying to find an answer to my issue but with no luck.
I am not sure if the issue is somewhere in my CSV or in the phpMyAdmin import settings.

Here is an example of the first two lines of my CSV file that I am trying to import...

```
'CA1923', '6320 Canoga Avenue', '', '6320 Canoga Avenue', NULL, 'Woodland Hills', 'CA', '91367', 'USA', NULL, NULL, NULL, 'info@connexusvideo.com', NULL, NULL, '0', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '0', NULL, NULL, '0', 'http://www.google.com/mapfiles/markerN.png', '-118.5961599', '34.1851569', '12', '8', '42', '1', '0', '6320 Canoga Avenue Woodland Hills CA', '6320 Canoga Avenue Woodland Hills CA', '0', 'CA1923', '0', '6', '0',
'CA1927', '425 Market Street', '', '425 Market Street', NULL, 'San Francisco', 'CA', '94105', 'USA', NULL, NULL, NULL, 'info@connexusvideo.com', NULL, NULL, '0', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '0', NULL, NULL, '0', 'http://www.google.com/mapfiles/markerN.png', '-122.3981953', '37.7912401', '12', '8', '42', '1', '0', '425 Market Street San Francisco CA', '425 Market Street San Francisco CA', '0', 'CA1927', '0', '7', '0',
```

Here is the column headers exported out of the SQL file for this table...

```
INSERT INTO `conx_gmapfp` (`id`, `nom`, `alias`, `adresse`, `adresse2`, `ville`, `departement`, `codepostal`, `pay`, `tel`, `tel2`, `fax`, `email`, `web`, `img`, `album`, `intro`, `message`, `horaires_prix`, `link`, `article_id`, `icon`, `icon_label`, `affichage`, `marqueur`, `glng`, `glat`, `gzoom`, `catid`, `userid`, `published`, `checked_out`, `metadesc`, `metakey`, `ordering`, `room_id`, `distance`, `ZipRmID`, `rStatus`) VALUES
```

The import settings that I think should work are the following...

FORMAT = CSV

Replace Data Table With File = CHECKED

Columns separated with: ,

Columns enclosed with: '

Columns escaped with: /

Lines terminated with: auto

However, everytime I get this error **"Invalid column count in CSV input on line 1."**

I have 39 columns in the existing table & there are 39 columns on the CSV. Every column is seperated with a , and enclosed with a '

What is the issue here & how do I fix this? I have spent all day trying to figure out what the simple solution is but can't figure it out. I know it must be basic but I have tried anything. I give up. HELP!

Comment: It clearly mean that your **destination table column count does not match with CSV column count**. Check the column and also post your table structure or create table syntax here. It will help to analyse the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the response @VazhgaValamudan ! Yes I have checked the column & seems correct to the best of my understanding. I just added the column headers exported out of the SQL of this table above. Any help figuring this out is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

WIth phpmyadmin import, despite making sure you have the right number of columns as in the table this error message occurs if there are commas within the values themselves.

In that case it should import successfully with the following options..

- FORMAT: CSV with LOAD DATA
- Columns terminated by: ,
- Columns enclosed with: "
- Columns escaped by: \
- Lines terminated by: auto

Comment: Using `CSV with LOAD DATA` has solved the problem for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:**

This issue because of Your **sample data rows(lines) end with ,(comma)**. So system unable to identify the row. That is system consider second record also continuation of first record. So  you got **"Invalid column count in CSV input on line 1."**.

**Solution:**

Remove ,(comma) from each end of the row(line). Then you can import without problem.

Import the below Sample Data:

```
'CA1923', '6320 Canoga Avenue', '', '6320 Canoga Avenue', NULL, 'Woodland Hills', 'CA', '91367', 'USA', NULL, NULL, NULL, 'info@connexusvideo.com', NULL, NULL, '0', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '0', NULL, NULL, '0', 'http://www.google.com/mapfiles/markerN.png', '-118.5961599', '34.1851569', '12', '8', '42', '1', '0', '6320 Canoga Avenue Woodland Hills CA', '6320 Canoga Avenue Woodland Hills CA', '0', 'CA1923', '0', '6', '0'
'CA1927', '425 Market Street', '', '425 Market Street', NULL, 'San Francisco', 'CA', '94105', 'USA', NULL, NULL, NULL, 'info@connexusvideo.com', NULL, NULL, '0', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '0', NULL, NULL, '0', 'http://www.google.com/mapfiles/markerN.png', '-122.3981953', '37.7912401', '12', '8', '42', '1', '0', '425 Market Street San Francisco CA', '425 Market Street San Francisco CA', '0', 'CA1927', '0', '7', '0'
```

Comment: thanks so much for this & that makes total sense. However, I cannot figure out how to remove the , at the end of each row as I dont even see those comma whens viewing in excel but it is how the CSV is made when I export it out of excel. How would I remove the comma at the end of each row of the CSV for 1742 rows? THANKS!

Comment: The rows I have originally are provided to me like this...
    "(1, '6320 Canoga Avenue', '', '6320 Canoga Avenue', NULL, 'Woodland Hills', 'CA', '91367', 'USA', NULL, NULL, NULL, 'info@connexusvideo.com', NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL, 0, 'http://www.google.com/mapfiles/markerN.png', '-118.5961599', '34.1851569', '12', 8, 42, 1, 0, '6320 Canoga Avenue Woodland Hills CA', '6320 Canoga Avenue Woodland Hills CA', 0, 'CA1923', '0', '6', '0'),"

Comment: 1. Open the csv file with wordpad (in windows) or gedit (in linux) 2. Find **),**  or equalent pattern and replace with empty char.