# Mysql collation/type for csv import error Invalid column count in CSV input on line 1362

Tags: python, mysql, database, csv, phpmyadmin

I have data in a csv which I am trying to import into a database using the Mysql GUI with the format "CSV".

When doing so I get an error: "Invalid column count in CSV input on line 1362."

In the CSV file line 1362 contains text with characters that have accents, when the accents are removed this error goes away. However, some other lines containing the same accented characters are imported without any error.

**How I set up my database and csv file**

The csv file was created with python's csv.writer. When using the GUI to import the data I chose the option showing "Character set of the file: utf-8"

The collation of the entire database is `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci`. The column with the problematic characters has type Varchar(250) with collation utf8_bin.

**What I tried**

Based on some of the answers to the below questions I tried changing the collation of the column and the database to `utf_unicode_ci`, and `utf16`. I tried using the format "CSV Load Data".

[Multilingual Datatype in MYSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13081934/multilingual-datatype-in-mysql)

[Trouble importing/replacing a table w CSV in phpMyAdmin: Invalid column count in CSV input on line 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695726/trouble-importing-replacing-a-table-w-csv-in-phpmyadmin-invalid-column-count-in)

When using CSV Load Data I got the following error:

```
#1300 - Invalid utf8mb4 character string: '"Bille na dTeangacha Oifigi'
```

I'd note that in the text the character following the above string is an accented character which causes the error.

The same error referencing `utf8mb4` occurs even when the collation of the column is `utf_unicode_ci`. From this I figure that the problem is that the collation of the entire table is `utf8mb4`.

The error messages seem to point to the collation as being the source of the problem. I have tried so many combinations of collations but haven't made any progress. Can anyone point me in the right direction for how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue. The problem was in how the csv file had been created. I had to specify that python saves the file with utf-8 encoding. Something like this:

```
with open('foobar.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
for row in tempTable:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(row)
```